# How to select the default database in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

If I attach a database to SQLite:

```sql
ATTACH DATABASE 'my.db' AS 'mydb';
```

**Is it possible to set the default database for consecutive SQL statements?**

So that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table;
```

Would be translated to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mydb.table;
```

Instead of:

```sql
SELECT * FROM main.table;
```

Just like `USE mydb` in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is always the default database.

To make `mydb` the default database, you have to open it directly.

Comment: Makes sense I guess. I could just do the opposite: open `my.db` first, then attach the other one.